# Efficient way to get text as images?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a machine learning task and I need to create training data which consists of short strings of text represented as gray scale images. In the end I want the data in 2D numpy arrays. My current approach is to use matplotlib to write generated text on a blank axis, then use a few tricks to essentially grab the underlying data into a numpy array.  This is somewhat slow though, with matplotlib bringing up and tearing down figures for every example (I do have the figures hidden and not showing). Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.  This is a very broad question in application design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are various ways, you can try using [pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/2.2.2/)

Using pillow (called in as PIL) you can control text/number to draw, its size, font, position and background color etc.
Pillow site can provide with more options for building a robust and varied data-sets.

You can vary the constants per your requirements , [details here](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html).

Here's working code - We are creating image for text '100' here.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import numpy as np

#Number to draw
number_to_draw = "100"

#define image width , height and color
image_width, image_height = (300,200)
image_background = "grey"

#Set font size and type
fontsize = 35
font = ImageFont.truetype('/Library/Fonts/Arial.ttf', 45)

#prep image
im = Image.new("L",(image_width,image_height),image_background)

#Convert to numpy array
im2arr = np.array(im)
print(im2arr)

#Draw image
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

#Set position and draw image
w, h = draw.textsize(number_to_draw)
draw.text(((image_width-w)/2,(image_height-h)/2), number_to_draw, font=font)

#Save to file
im.save("100.png", "PNG")

#show image to screen
im.show()
```

Output & Saved Image

```
$python text2image.py 
[[128 128 128 ... 128 128 128]
 [128 128 128 ... 128 128 128]
 [128 128 128 ... 128 128 128]
 ...
 [128 128 128 ... 128 128 128]
 [128 128 128 ... 128 128 128]
 [128 128 128 ... 128 128 128]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to go straight to numpy array without saving to disk first?  I can research this myself too...

Comment: yeah - super easy. Just import numpy and convert im to arry. `import numpy as np` and `im2arr = np.array(im)`. Answer updated accordingly.